# How can I center divs vertically and horizontally in a container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block new-block"></div>
  <div class="block used-block"></div>
  <div class="block service-block"></div>
  <div class="block certified-block"></div>
  <div class="block offer-type-block"></div>
</div>
```

And the following css with it:

```
.wrapper {
  width : 800px;
  height : 100px;
  background : #393533;
  margin : auto;
}

.block {
  width : 19%;
  height : 80px;
  background : salmon;
  display : inline-block;
}
```

I want to center the inner 5 divs horizontally and vertically in the container wrapper container, how can I achieve this using css. Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use CSS flexbox on the wrapper and align contents to center:

```css
.wrapper {
  width : 800px;
  height : 100px;
  background : #393533;
  margin : auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  width : 19%;
  height : 80px;
  background : salmon;
  display : inline-block;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block new-block">test</div>
  <div class="block used-block">test</div>
  <div class="block service-block">test</div>
  <div class="block certified-block">test</div>
  <div class="block offer-type-block">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you think you should mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey - Already done.

Comment: Sounds Good....

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. May be it can help you out

```
 .wrapper {
        width : 800px;
        height : 100px;
        background : #393533;
        margin : auto;
        position: relative;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Sample Code </title>
  <style>
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #393533;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
.block {
  width : 19%;
  height : 80px;
  background : salmon;
  display : inline-block;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block new-block"></div>
  <div class="block used-block"></div>
  <div class="block service-block"></div>
  <div class="block certified-block"></div>
  <div class="block offer-type-block"></div>
</div>



   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `clearfix` is not there

Comment: @prasad please find the updated solution